# Use selected values to calculate a new value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select campaign
,ISNULL(sum(cast (HandleTime as bigint)), 0) handleTime
,(select Contacts from [View_ContactsByCampaign] Con where Con.Campaign = C.Campaign) Contacts
, ContactPerTime = Contacts / handleTime
from call C
group by campaign
```

I'm having problem calculating ContactPerTime value. I'm getting "Invalid column name 'Contacts'." and "Invalid column name 'handleTime'" errors. Is it possible to use the values for calculating?

Comment: Try through `CTE` or `subquery`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference another column in your `SELECT` statement by alias. if you need the expression again, you need repeat said expression:

```
SELECT campaign,
       ISNULL(SUM(CAST (HandleTime AS bigint)), 0) AS handleTime,
       (SELECT Contacts
        FROM [View_ContactsByCampaign] Con
        WHERE Con.Campaign = C.Campaign) AS Contacts,
       (SELECT Contacts
        FROM [View_ContactsByCampaign] Con
        WHERE Con.Campaign = C.Campaign) / handleTime AS ContactPerTime
FROM [CALL] C
GROUP BY campaign;
```

However, as what you have is a subquery, you'd be better off using `APPLY`. Probably something like::

```
SELECT campaign,
       ISNULL(SUM(CAST (HandleTime AS bigint)), 0) AS handleTime,
       Con.Contacts
       Con.Contacts / handleTime AS ContactPerTime
FROM [CALL] C
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT Contacts
                 FROM [View_ContactsByCampaign] ca
                 WHERE ca.Campaign = C.Campaign) Con
--Considering that Contacts was returned from a subquery, it's likely a "safe"
--assumption it will return 1 row. If it didn't, then your previous query
--would have errored anyway.
GROUP BY campaign, Contacts;
```

For reference, have a look at [Logical Processing Order of the `SELECT` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement): which states:

> Conversely, because the `SELECT` clause is step 8, any column aliases or
>   derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by
>   preceding clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent
>   clauses such as the `ORDER BY` clause.

`ORDER BY` is actually the only place you can reference a column by alias in the same part of statement.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I will be able to apply the first method

Comment: I'd recommend using `APPLY`. Using 2 subselects means 2 tables scans. The `APPLY` would only need 1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.But I still get error Invalid column name 'handleTime'. My query 

select five9_campaign
,(ISNULL(sum(cast (Five9_HandleTime as bigint)), 1)) as handleTime
,Con.Contacts
,Con.Contacts / handleTime as ContactPerTime
from telefund_call C
cross apply(select Contacts from [ContactsByCampaign] ca where ca.Five9_Campaign = C.Five9_Campaign) Con
group by Five9_campaign, Contacts

Comment: `handleTime` is also an alias. The initial error only pointed to `Contacts`. I've given you the relevant information as to why, so I'm sure you can work out why and fix. The user's here aren't here to hand hold you the whole way. :)